# PHP - Dropdown function that keeps current page in focus

Tags: php, html

I have a drop-down navigation that brings the user to the page selected in the drop-down once the user clicks a button. I have a function that takes in the page section title as a parameter and builds a new drop-down with that page on top of the list, so that each page you navigate to will remain in focus in the drop-down. The function is a massive switch case with a lot of repetitive code and I know there's an easier and cleaner way of doing this... I'm just having trouble thinking of a solution. Here's a code snippet, I won't post the entire switch case:

```
function makeDropDown($page){ 
switch ($page){
    case 'uploads':
      echo '<center><form action="pictures.php" action="get">
         <select name="pictype">
         <option value="uploads">Uploads</option>
         <option value="fromweb">From Web</option>
         <option value="wallpapers">Wallpapers</option>
         <option value="misc">Miscellaneous</option>
         </select>
         <input type="submit" value = "Go!"/>
         </form></center>'; break;
   case 'fromweb':
      echo '<center><form action="pictures.php" action="get">
         <select name="pictype">
         <option value="fromweb">From Web</option>
         <option value="uploads">Uploads</option>
         <option value="wallpapers">Wallpapers</option>
         <option value="misc">Miscellaneous</option>
         </select>
         <input type="submit" value = "Go!"/>
         </form></center>'; break;
   case 'wallpapers':
      echo '<center><form action="pictures.php" action="get">
         <select name="pictype">
         <option value="wallpapers">Wallpapers</option>
         <option value="uploads">Uploads</option>
         <option value="fromweb">From Web</option>
         <option value="misc">Miscellaneous</option>
         </select>
         <input type="submit" value = "Go!"/>
         </form></center>'; break;
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of moving the selected item to the top of the list, why not try using the `selected` attribute of the option items. This will initialize the select box to the selected option. simply echo `selected` in the option that matches the value of `$page`

```
function makeDropDown($page){ 
    echo '<center><form action="pictures.php" action="get">';
    echo '    <select name="pictype">';
    echo '        <option value="uploads"'.(($page=="uploads")? " selected":"").'>Uploads</option>';
    echo '        <option value="fromweb"'.(($page=="fromweb")? " selected":"").'>From Web</option>';
    echo '        <option value="wallpapers"'.(($page=="wallpapers")? " selected":"").'>Wallpapers</option>';
    echo '        <option value="misc"'.(($page=="misc")? " selected":"").'>Miscellaneous</option>';
    echo '    </select>';
    echo '    <input type="submit" value = "Go!"/>';
    echo '</form></center>';
}
```

This way, if `$page=='misc'`, your HTML will result this way

```
<center><form action="pictures.php" action="get">
    <select name="pictype">
        <option value="uploads">Uploads</option>
        <option value="fromweb">From Web</option>
        <option value="wallpapers">Wallpapers</option>
        <option value="misc" selected>Miscellaneous</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value = "Go!"/>
</form></center>'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try echo-ing this at the end beginning of each case:

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.getElementsByName(name).focus();</script>
```

Hope that helps.