# Set value of select element based on GET parameters, without JavaScript?

Tags: html

Here's a very basic HTML question for you:

```
<form method="get" action="#">
<select id="u" name="u">  
<option value="nothing" title=""></option> 
<option value="AdamT" title="AT">Adam Temple</option>  
<option value="AlexP" title="AP">Alex Potts</option> 
</select>
<INPUT TYPE="submit" />
</form>
```

After submitting the form, the URL ends `?u=AdamT`. However, the list has reverted to the blank element.

Is there any way I could make the list be pre-selected with the correct option, without using JavaScript?

Comment: is using php/asp/what-have-you to put it directly in the html before it's sent over to the client cheating?

Comment: As @anq implies, this isn't possible with plain html. If you're able to use a server-side language it's easiest, failing that JavaScript can do it. But it's more of a kerfuffle, or bodge, with JS.

Comment: There is an extremely detailed answer located here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4832424/php-dropdown-function-that-keeps-current-page-in-focus/4832454#4832454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `selected` (its a boolean attribute) to the appropriate `<option>` element in whatever server side language you use to process the form.

Answer (score 0):

Put your javascript at the end of html script or include the .js at the end of the body.

```
var val = location.href.match(/[?&]u=(.*?)(?:$|&)/)[1];   // get params "u" from URL
document.getElementById("you-selection-id").value = val; // u
```

Hope this will help:

Answer (score -1):

Use `selected` for preselected values

`<option value="AdamT" title="AT" selected>Adam Temple</option>`